# How to recursively delete files and folders under a certain directory using command line?

Tags: linux

I am a beginner of Linux system. Now I have a butch of files and folders want to be deleted. How can delete them one time using some command line?

Comment: As a beginner on Linux, get familiar with using `man` pages. For example, you view the full details of the remove `rm` command with `man rm`. The pages may look at bit cryptic at first, but they are concisely written to provide you all relevant information about a command (some may further refer you to `info` pages for additional detail) Moreover, all posix compliant commands will respond to the `--help` option by listing a short description and all relevant options. Try both with `rm`, e.g. `rm --help` and `man rm`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly I think you need **rm** command, then since you want to recursively delete the files or folders, you have to choose the option -r, -r means recursively delete something. Below is the link for details using **rm** command in Linux system.

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm

Comment: rm command supports multiple file names, so you can use -r and also provide multiple file names in a single go. eg rm -r <folder1> <file1> <folder2>....